# Get the inner text of an HTML tag and pass as value to an input field using JavaScript and EJS

Tags: javascript, html, dom, input, dom-events

I am working with a grid container and each grid-item has an **image and a h3** tag wrapped in an anchor tag which links to a popup form;

```
<a href="#popup" class="grid-item">
      <div>
        <img
          src="/assets/images/Rainbow.jpeg"
          class="grid-image"
          alt="?Icon"
        />
        <h3 class="wallet-text">Rainbow</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
    <a href="#popup" class="grid-item">
      <div>
        <img
          src="/assets/images/TrustWallet.jpeg"
          class="grid-image"
          alt="?Icon"
        />
        <h3 class="wallet-text">Trust Wallet</h3>
      </div>
    </a>
```

What I am trying to achieve is have the **text** of the h3 tag passed as the input value of the **wallet Name Field** when I click on any wallet. This is what the **popup form** looks like:

```
<form action="/link" class="pop-up-form" method="POST">
  <a href="#wallet-box" class="close-btn">&times;</a>

  <!-- single field -->
  <div class="data">
    <label>Wallet ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="wallet_id" required />
  </div>
  <!-- single field -->



  <!-- single field -->
  <div class="data">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" required />
  </div>
  <!-- single field -->



  <!-- single field -->
  <div class="data">
    <label>Wallet Name</label>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="wallet_name"
      id="wallet_name"
      value=""
      required
    />
  </div>
  <!-- single field -->
  <button class="btn-box btn-transparent px-5">Link</button>
</form>
```

Comment: > "have the text of the h3 tag passed as the input value of the wallet Name Field when **I click on any wallet**." You mean when someone click on a `grid-item`?

Comment: yes, when anyone click on a grid-item the <h3> text of that grid-item should be passed into the wallet_name field as it's value

Answer (score 0):

- Just create an `EventListener` when click on a `grid-item`. Create a `wallet` variable that will save the `wallet-text` value and then put it in the `wallet_name` input field:

```js
let items = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName("grid-item"));

items.forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", function(){
    let wallet = this.getElementsByClassName("wallet-text")[0].innerHTML;
    document.getElementById("wallet_name").value = wallet;
  });
});
```

```html
<a href="#popup" class="grid-item">
  <div>
    <img src="/assets/images/Rainbow.jpeg" class="grid-image" alt="?Icon" />
    <h3 class="wallet-text">Rainbow</h3>
  </div>
</a>
<a href="#popup" class="grid-item">
  <div>
    <img src="/assets/images/TrustWallet.jpeg" class="grid-image" alt="?Icon" />
    <h3 class="wallet-text">Trust Wallet</h3>
  </div>
</a>

<form action="/link" class="pop-up-form" method="POST">
  <a href="#wallet-box" class="close-btn">&times;</a>
  <!-- single field -->
  <div class="data">
    <label>Wallet ID</label>
    <input type="text" name="wallet_id" required />
  </div>
  <!-- single field -->
  <!-- single field -->
  <div class="data">
    <label>Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" required />
  </div>
  <!-- single field -->
  <!-- single field -->
  <div class="data">
    <label>Wallet Name</label>
    <input type="text" name="wallet_name" id="wallet_name" value="" required />
  </div>
  <!-- single field -->
  <button class="btn-box btn-transparent px-5">Link</button>
</form>
```